# How to find the first-order homogeneous system of linear differential equations if the fundamental solutions are given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Now I know the fundamental solutions are two column vectors $$u(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ v(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t^2 \\ 3t  \end{pmatrix} $$
Then how do I know which first-order homogeneous system of linear differential equations has these fundamental solutions?

My attempt:
a first-order homogeneous system of linear differential equations has form **x' = Ax**

I think since the linear combination of fundamental solutions forms a general solution to the system. I just let $$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1t+\alpha_2t^2  \\ \alpha_1+3\alpha_2t\end{pmatrix}$$
be a general solution where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are two arbitrary constants. Then I let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a(t) & b(t)   \\ c(t) & d(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, I plug these into the first-order homogeneous system of linear differential equations **x' = Ax**.  Thus I can get
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1+2\alpha_2t  \\ 3\alpha_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a(t) & b(t)   \\ c(t) & d(t)\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1t+\alpha_2t^2  \\ \alpha_1+3\alpha_2t\end{pmatrix}$$

By solving this, I think I can get fixed $a,b,c,d$. But I failed.

Any help on this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I set up $$\pmatrix{1&2t\cr0&3\cr}=A\pmatrix{t&t^2\cr1&3t\cr}$$ and got $$A={1\over2t^2}\pmatrix{t&t^2\cr-3&3t\cr}$$

Comment: I see you directly let $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$. Is it okay to do this?

Comment: That's not really what I did. You looked at linear combinations of $u$ and $v$; I'm looking at $u$ and $v$ separately.